# Affine arc length

Tags: differential-geometry, affine-geometry, arc-length

I was looking for an analog of arc length for plane curves in affine geometry, but I have only found the equi-affine arc length $d\sigma ={ || \gamma '(t)\wedge \gamma ''(t) ||}^{1 \over 3}dt$. On Wikipedia there is something, but it is not invariant under the action of the affine group. 
Any suggestion? And why everyone cares only about equi-affine geometry?

Comment: If you use $GL(2)$ rather than $SL(2)$, why do you think there will be any invariant notion?

Comment: You say that there is not such invariant?

Comment: None of which I'm aware. There's sloppiness in books/literature about calling affine differential geometry special-affine or equi-affine, but it always is, I believe. Also, you might look at Blaschke's differential geometry book (which I used to have in German, but no longer have); but he has an entire volume on affine differential geometry.

Comment: Do you think it is an intrisic characteristic of affine geometry the lack of such invariant or it is just because equi-affine geometry is simpler to study? Because there is for $E(2)$, $SL(2)$, $PGL(2)$... I cannot see an intuitive reason why $GL(2)$ could not have it! My expectation was an invariant that involve the third, fourth, maybe fifth, derivative

Comment: Mmm.. Applying Cartan's method I've found $d\sigma = \sqrt{\alpha + {2 \over 9}\beta ^ 2 - {1 \over 3} \beta '}dt$ where $P: I \to \mathbb{A}^2$ is the curve, with $P'$, $P''$ linearly indipendent and $P''' = \alpha P' + \beta P''$. Surely I know that it is invariant under the action of $GL(2)$ because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are too. I don't know if it is invariant under different parametrization: I could only test for $t \to kt$, otherwise it's too long. The only big problem is that we need $\alpha + {2 \over 9} \beta ^ 2 - {1 \over 3}  \beta ' \gt 0$. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marco,

I'm not aware of any notion of (non-equi-)affine arc length defined in the the literature - but the one you've constructed above, i.e., 
$$d\sigma = \sqrt{\alpha + \tfrac{2}{9} \beta^2 - \tfrac{1}{3} \beta'}\, dt, $$
looks pretty natural to me.  I did a quick Maple calculation and verified that it is, in fact, invariant under arbitrary reparametrizations of the curve, so it seems as good a definition as any.

As to your point about the sign - what's really invariant is the quadratic form
$$ Q = \left(\alpha + \tfrac{2}{9} \beta^2 - \tfrac{1}{3} \beta' \right) dt^2. $$
Of course, one could just as well have chosen the invariant quadratic form $-Q$, and then it would seem equally natural to define
$$d\sigma = \sqrt{-\left(\alpha + \tfrac{2}{9} \beta^2 - \tfrac{1}{3} \beta'\right)}\, dt. $$
Personally, my inclination would be to call the curve "nondegenerate" (or some other word meaning "nice") if the quadratic form $Q$ never vanishes, and then define the affine arc length element to be
$$ d\sigma = \sqrt{|\alpha + \tfrac{2}{9} \beta^2 - \tfrac{1}{3} \beta'|}\, dt. $$

Comment: Thank you for the reply! An answer from you, who are such an expert of this, is really important for me. I wrote how I got $d\sigma$. I am not too much happy with this $d\sigma$ because, for example, I have $d\sigma = 0$ for the classic hyperbola $(t, 1/t)$ and parabola $(t, t^2)$. I also *feel* that the sign is important, because for the ellipses $(a\cos t, b\sin t)$ I get $d\sigma^2 = -dt^2$ and for the hyperbolas $(a\cosh t, b\sinh t)$ I get $d\sigma^2 = dt^2$ and this is really the only thing that distinguish them because they both have $k \equiv 0$.

Comment: And instead introducing complex numbers? For example for the ellipses $d\sigma = idt$ and for the hyperbolas $d\bar\sigma = d\bar t$ so that $idt = d\bar t$ cannot be solved because the $dt$ are supposed to be real. Could it work in your opinion?

Comment: Or maybe I can take your $d\sigma$ and *then* define the Frenet frame as $e_1 = {dP \over d\sigma}$, $e_2 = {de_1 \over d\sigma}$. Than I will have $de_2 = (k_1e_1 + k_2e_2)d\sigma$. For the ellipses $k_1 = -1$ and $k_2 = 0$, for the hyperbolas $k_1 = 1$ and $k_2 = 0$. Could this work?

Comment: Sure, I think that's a completely reasonable definition for a Frenet frame.  It also seems perfectly plausible to me that the sign has significance, and it's interesting that it's different for ellipses and hyperbolas.

Comment: One way to try to understand what this invariant means might be to express it in terms of the Euclidean curvature $\kappa$.  If you assume the curve is parametrized by its Euclidean arc length $s$ with Euclidean Frenet frame $(T, N)$, then you have $P' = T$, $P'' = \kappa N$, $P''' = -\kappa^2 T + \kappa' N = -\kappa^2 P' + \frac{\kappa'}{\kappa} P''$, so
$d\sigma^2 =\left( -\kappa^2 + \frac{2\kappa'}{9\kappa} - \frac{(\kappa \kappa'' - \kappa'^2)}{3\kappa^2}\right) ds^2$.  I can't say that gives me any great intuition as to what it means, but it's a place to start exploring.

Comment: I tried to compare it with the *equi-affine* frame. Call $d\bar\sigma$ and $\bar k$ the equi-affine parameter and the equi-affine curvature. I got $d\sigma = \sqrt {\bar k} d\bar\sigma$. And... its the same of Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_curvature#Affine_curvature . Unfortunately when I red it I thought that $k(s)$ was the *euclidean* curvature, not the equi-affine one...

Answer (score 0):

I write two words about what I've found.

I followed the method exposed in *La théorie des groupes finis et continus et la géométrie différentielle traitées par la méthode du repère mobile* by E. Cartan. I found this book in my university's library.

I started with two frames, both with $(e_1, e_2)$ linearly indipendent and $e_1$ parallel to the tangent line. The change of frame is given by

$ e_1 = \lambda\bar {e}_1 \\ e_2 = \mu \bar {e}_1 + \eta \bar e_2$

which depends on 3 secondary parameters $(\lambda, \mu, \eta)$, with $\lambda \eta \neq 0$. I got

$ \omega ^1 = {1 \over \lambda} \bar \omega^1 \\
\omega^2 = \bar \omega ^2 = 0$

These are the two principal components of order zero. Then I got

$\omega_{1}^2 = {\lambda \over \eta} \bar \omega_1^2$

This is the principal component of first order. I chose $\omega_1^2 = \omega^1$ and I got

$\omega^1 = {\lambda \over \eta} \bar \omega^1 = {\lambda^2 \over \eta} \omega^1$

So $\eta = \lambda ^ 2$. Then I got

$\omega_1^1 = \bar \omega_1^1 - {\mu \over \lambda^2}\bar \omega_1^2 + {1 \over \lambda}d\lambda \\
\omega_2^2 = \bar \omega_2^2 + {\mu \over \lambda^2}\bar \omega_1^2 + {2 \over \lambda}d\lambda$

So the principal component of second order is $\omega_2^2 - 2\omega_1^1$. I chose $\omega_2^2 - 2\omega_1^1 = 0$. I got

$ 0 = 3{\mu \over \lambda^2}\bar \omega_1^2$

So $\mu = 0$. Then I got

$\omega_2^1 = \lambda \omega_2^1$

which is the principal component of third order. I chose $\omega_2^1 = \omega^1$. I got

$\omega^1 = \lambda \bar \omega^1 = \lambda^2 \omega^1$

So $\lambda^2 = 1$ and I chose $\lambda = 1$.

I have no more secondary parameters, so this is the *Frenet frame*. I have two invariants: $\omega^1$ and $\omega_1^1$. I defined $d\sigma$ and $k$ by $d\sigma = \omega^1$ and $\omega_1^1 = k\omega^1$. The *Frenet formulas* are

$dP = e_1d\sigma \\
de_1 = (ke_1 + e_2)d\sigma \\
de_2 = (e_1 + 2ke_2)d\sigma$

To obtain explicit formulas I considered $\bar e_1 = P'$ and $\bar e_2 = P''$. I got

$\bar \omega_1 = dt \\
\bar \omega_2 = 0 \\
\bar \omega_1^1 = 0 \\
\bar \omega_1^2 = dt \\
\bar \omega_2^1 = \alpha dt\\
\bar \omega_2^2 = \beta dt\\$

where $P''' = \alpha P' + \beta P''$. Considering $\omega_1^2 = \omega_2^1 = \omega^1$ and $\omega_2^2 = 2\omega_1^1$ I got

$e_1 = \lambda P' \\
e_2 = -{1 \over 3}\beta \lambda^2 P' + \lambda^2 P''$

where ${1 \over \lambda} = \sqrt{\alpha + {2 \over 9}\beta^2 - {1 \over 3}\beta '}$. Eventually I got

$d\sigma = {1 \over \lambda} dt \\
k = \lambda ' + {1 \over 3} \beta \lambda$

I hope there are not too many errors.